# Ionic Beta 10 iOS Build - You're trying to build for iosbut don't have the platform installed yet

Tags: xcode, macos, cordova, npm, ionic2

I've been developing on a Windows computer for Android just fine, but once got my hands on a Mac Mini. Once I got the OS updated to El Capitan, XCode installed, and everything else (NodeJS, Ionic, etc.) I tried to do a build for iOS and the build breaks saying:

> You're trying to build for iosbut don't have the platform installed yet.

My Ionic Setup is as follows:

> Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
>   Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
>   Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
>   Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
>   Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
>   ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
>   ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
>   OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
>   Node Version: v5.12.0
>   Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014

The error I get is as follows:

> Running 'build:before' gulp task before build
>   [23:21:58] Starting 'clean'...
>   [23:21:58] Finished 'clean' after 65 ms
>   [23:21:58] Starting 'build'...
>   [23:21:58] Starting 'sass'...
>   [23:21:58] Starting 'html'...
>   [23:21:58] Starting 'fonts'...
>   [23:21:58] Starting 'scripts'...
>   [23:21:58] Finished 'scripts' after 74 ms
>   [23:21:58] Finished 'fonts' after 85 ms
>   [23:21:58] Finished 'html' after 95 ms
>   [23:21:59] Finished 'sass' after 1.11 s
>   [23:22:10] Finished 'build' after 12 s
>   [23:22:10] Starting 'build:before'...
>   [23:22:10] Finished 'build:before' after 7.64 μs
>   
>   • You're trying to build for iosbut don't have the platform installed yet.
>   ∆ Installing ios for you.
>   Installing cordova-plugin-device
>   Installing cordova-plugin-console
>   Installing cordova-plugin-whitelist
>   Installing cordova-plugin-splashscreen
>   Installing cordova-plugin-statusbar
>   Installing ionic-plugin-keyboard
>   Caught exception:
>    Error: Command failed: cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-device
>   Parsing /Users/esx/projects/xcatalyst%20mobile%20app/config.xml failed
>   Error: Unencoded <
>   Line: 2
>   Column: 2
>   Char: <
>   
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:202:12)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)

As a side note, I did have Node v6.?.? and Cordova v6.3.0 installed, but there where issues where Cordova CLI showed up as Not Installed when executing "ionic info".

I've also tried to execute "ionic state reset" but get a similar error:

> Removed platforms and plugins
>   Attempting to restore your Ionic application from package.json
>   
>   Restoring Platforms
>   
>   cordova platform add ios
>   cordova platform add android
>   
>   Restore platforms is complete
>   
>   Restoring Plugins
>   
>   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
>   Caught exception:
>    undefined

This is my first attempt using a Mac and trying to build an Ionic app using one. I've followed (or tried to) the setup information on the Ionic site ([OSX Setup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/platform-setup/mac-setup.html)).

I'm unsure of how to track either of these errors down.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try using older version of node, `0.12.7` always worked for me. Use NVM to change node version btw.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my config.xml, which had some invalid characters and syntax issues. I guess when building for the android platform this didn't matter, but it did/does for iOS builds.